# DataTables Smart Search - not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, regex, search, filter, datatables

The documentation for the search() function specifies the functionality:

> Match words out of order. For example if you search for Allan Fife it would match a row containing the words Allan and Fife, regardless of the order or position that they appear in the table.

However I don't think this is the case. If you search "chief junior" (without brackets) on this example https://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html you would expect all results containing either "chief" or "junior" to be returned but the API seems to use AND rather than OR.

I'm trying to create a multi select drop down to filter a table but I need to be able to select more than one parameter. Is there a way to tell the API to us OR rather than AND or is this not available?

Comment: Was any of the answers helpful to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the DataTables documentation for the [search function](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) is correct but not very clear:

The "smart" searching for words out of order does just that - and not an either/or search.

For example, if you search in the Position column of that example table, you get the same rows whether you search for `Chief Officer` or `Officer Chief`.

But you do not get any rows when you search the Name column for `Airi Ramos` (first name in row 1 and last name in row 2).

To do so, you could *additionally* switch on regex and search for `Airi.*|.*Ramos` As you can see, the position is now important. To get the second row you have to allow any number of characters before `Ramos` (the `.*` after `Airi`, however, is not required, which is a bit inconsistent in my book).

If you turn off the smart search and switch exclusively to regex you get a behavior that is closer to your expectations: (A|B) matches all rows whose search column contains A or B - regardless of position.

Comment: Thanks this worked! In my case I am using a dropdown to search for companies so the value that I search for matches the column value exactly. Sometimes the company has a space in it eg "Apple Inc" and I found that using ".*" didn't work for these values but just a simple "|" worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I think you misread the original text you quoted - "For example if you search for Allan Fife it would match a row containing the words Allan and Fife". Note, it says "a row" that contains the words Allan and Fife. In your example, "chief junior", there isn't a single row that contains both those words.

If you want any row that contains either "chief" or "junior", then enter "(junior|chief)", tick "Treat as a regex" and untick "Use smart search".